# Issue with JBPM 5.3.1

Tags: jbpm

In my application currently I upgraded jar of Spring, Hibenate & JBPM

Spring3 to Spring4.2

Hibernate3 to Hibernate4

JBPM5.3.0 to JBPM 5.3.1

But after upgrading jar I am getting below Exception.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown entity: org.jbpm.persistence.processinstance.ProcessInstanceInfo
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:878)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:344)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy98.persist(Unknown Source)
    at org.jbpm.persistence.JpaProcessPersistenceContext.persist(JpaProcessPersistenceContext.java:22)
    at org.jbpm.persistence.processinstance.JPAProcessInstanceManager.addProcessInstance(JPAProcessInstanceManager.java:49)
    at org.jbpm.process.instance.AbstractProcessInstanceFactory.createProcessInstance(AbstractProcessInstanceFactory.java:36)
    at org.jbpm.process.instance.ProcessRuntimeImpl.startProcess(ProcessRuntimeImpl.java:183)
    at org.jbpm.process.instance.ProcessRuntimeImpl.createProcessInstance(ProcessRuntimeImpl.java:155)
    at org.jbpm.process.instance.ProcessRuntimeImpl.startProcess(ProcessRuntimeImpl.java:136)
    at org.drools.common.AbstractWorkingMemory.startProcess(AbstractWorkingMemory.java:1082)
    at org.drools.impl.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.startProcess(StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:318)
    at org.drools.command.runtime.process.StartProcessCommand.execute(StartProcessCommand.java:119)
    at org.drools.command.runtime.process.StartProcessCommand.execute(StartProcessCommand.java:38)
    at org.drools.command.impl.DefaultCommandService.execute(DefaultCommandService.java:36)
    at org.drools.persistence.SingleSessionCommandService.execute(SingleSessionCommandService.java:360)
    at org.drools.command.impl.CommandBasedStatefulKnowledgeSession.startProcess(CommandBasedStatefulKnowledgeSession.java:223)
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Kindly observe proper formatting of your post. Use code or blockquote tags as needed.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `ProcessInstanceInfo` is missing in your `persistence.xml` but there can be many other reasons why it does not work since you have updated both Spring and Hibernate to the next major version.

I wonder why you use almost the latest version of Spring but use several years old version of jBPM. Not even jBPM 6.4 supports Spring 4 but it will probably be supported in jBPM 6.5.

Comment: ProcessInstanceInfo  already there in persistence.xml. But still I am getting same exception.